# How can we detect interest points in image using histogram Methods in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

Kindly 
I just want to know how can we detect interest points in  an image using histogram Methods in MATLAB becouse i want to apply this in feature extraction Method.

regards

Comment: Please improve your question - e.g. what have you tried?

Comment: With MATLAB's Computer Vision Toolbox: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/feature-detection-extraction-and-matching.html

Comment: Dear jost,
i'm trying to apply feature extraction Method in an image to use it in Mobile Visual Search topic.
the first step of the feature extraction algorithm algorithm is to perform interest point detection on the query image,so i'm trying to perform it by histogram but i don't know if there is such implementation or not ...

Answer (score 0):

The Computer Vision System Toolbox provides a number of [interest point detectors and feature descriptors](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/point-feature-types.html).